# Difference between internal and external buffers .net

Tags: c#, .net, stream

some streams have internal buffers and some want external in a method parameter. Whats the difference between them and what are the reasons for each.

Greetings

Comment: Can you give an example? I am not sure your question is clear enough.

Comment: `var ms = new MemoryStream(new byte[65535]); ms.Write(externalBuffer, 0, 10);` think he's talking about that. Or for file streams when you can specify the allocation size for the internal buffer and then use another buffer when invoking Read/Write

Comment: I am meaning the first option. But never thought about FileStream, it has an "internal" buffer, but also needs a second buffer for reading/writing...